# '(Int)->String' is not convertible to 'String' in an Array (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode6

I am trying to pass information from another view controller into the one with the code below and put the information into an Array. However, I am constantly getting an error no matter how I try to insert it. Have any suggestions?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate{
var user = PFUser()

@IBAction func logoutButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFUser.logOut()
    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Something Went Wrong", message:"Could not logout. Please try again later." , delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
        alert.show()
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var schedule: UIImageView!

var recievedBlocks = [String]()

func blockOutput (block: Int)->String{
    if (block == 1){
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[0])"
    }else if(block == 2){
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[1])"
    }else if(block == 3){
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[2])"
    }else if(block == 4){
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[3])"
    }else if(block == 5){
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[4])"
    }else if(block == 6){
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[5])"
    }else if(block == 7){
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[6])"
    }else if(block == 8){
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[7])"
    }else{
        return "\(self.recievedBlocks[8])"
    }
}

var monday = [
    ("8:30-9:30",blockOutput(1)),
    ("9:34-9:48","Advisory"),
    ("9:52-10:52","Block 2"),
    ("10:56-11:56","Block 3"),
    ("11:56-12:36","Lunch"),
    ("12:40-1:39","Block 4"),
    ("1:43-2:42","Block 5"),
    ("2:46-3:45","Block 6")]
```

Comment: Your monday is an array of String and you are passing ("8:30-9:30",blockOutput(1)) as element which is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate{
var user = PFUser()

@IBAction func logoutButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFUser.logOut()
    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Something Went Wrong", message:"Could not logout. Please try again later." , delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
        alert.show()
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var schedule: UIImageView!

var recievedBlocks = [String]()

func blockOutput (block: Int)->String{
    if (block == 1){
        return self.recievedBlocks[0]
    }else if(block == 2){
        return self.recievedBlocks[1]
    }else if(block == 3){
        return self.recievedBlocks[2]
    }else if(block == 4){
        return self.recievedBlocks[3]
    }else if(block == 5){
        return self.recievedBlocks[4]
    }else if(block == 6){
        return self.recievedBlocks[5]
    }else if(block == 7){
        return self.recievedBlocks[6]
    }else if(block == 8){
        return self.recievedBlocks[7]
    }else{
        return self.recievedBlocks[8]
    }
}

var monday:(String,String)[] = [
    ("8:30-9:30",blockOutput(1)),
    ("9:34-9:48","Advisory"),
    ("9:52-10:52","Block 2"),
    ("10:56-11:56","Block 3"),
    ("11:56-12:36","Lunch"),
    ("12:40-1:39","Block 4"),
    ("1:43-2:42","Block 5"),
    ("2:46-3:45","Block 6")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to call `blockOutput(1)` inside of a property. You will need to move it to a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var recievedBlocks :[String] = ["Block 1","Block 2","Block 3","Advisory4","Advisory5"]

var monday:[(String,String)] = []

func blockOutput(block: Int) -> String {
    return recievedBlocks.count > block ? recievedBlocks[block] : ""
}

monday = [("8:30-9:30", blockOutput(1)),("9:34-9:48","Advisory"),("9:52-10:52","Block 2"),("10:56-11:56","Block 3"),("11:56-12:36","Lunch"), ("12:40-1:39","Block 4"), ("1:43-2:42","Block 5"), ("2:46-3:45","Block 6")]
```